# Unable to remove directory "bin\Debug\app.publish". The directory is not empty

Tags: c#, visual-studio

When I attempt to start my project after making ANY change I get this error (even just commenting out a line them removing the comment tag).  I need to completely close out of MSVS and manually delete the folder to be able to re run the project.  I am unable to publish anything.

This just started last week and according to our network admin, nothing has changed permission-wise on the server, so it must be something I have done in the project.

Is there some audit I can perform to assist me in finding the offending code?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you running VS as administrator?

Comment: I am not sure.  I don't log in when I open the app.  I run it from my local station, if that helps (I do not remote to a server or log into the machine as an admin)

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove that app.publish 
first try to remove that by clean your solution if this not worked then 
then find that path where it is and then remove it yourself.
may this will work 
happing development....!!

Answer (score 0):

This was permissions issue for me.

I restarted visual studio and ran as administrator which enabled me to clean the project and publish without an issue